# authentication not working (vuejs / api php)

Tags: php, vue.js, axios

I have a simple login form which is working fine on local but when I'm trying to test the auth function on a deployment mode, it's giving me some problems (and a headache).

my backend is an api with php, working great on postman. here my auth function :

```
$login = $_POST['login'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if (empty($login) && empty($password)) {
    response(400, "Authentification obligatoire! Paramètres non fournis.", NULL);
}

try {
    $requete = $connection->prepare("SELECT login, password FROM user WHERE login = ?");
    $requete->execute([$login]);
    $user = $requete->fetch();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    response(500, $e->getMessage(), NULL);
}

if (empty($user) || $password != $user['password']) {
    response(401, "Le login ou le mot de passe ne correspond pas", NULL);
}
response(200, "authentifié", $login);
```

on my client side, I use vuejs and vuex to store the status (again, it's really simple). in my methods, I have a function :

```
connect() {
      const logForm = {
        login: this.login,
        password: this.password
      };
      console.log("log form", logForm);
      _axios
        .post("authentication", logForm, {
            headers: { 
              "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"}
          })
        .then(response => {
          console.log("response dans auth", response);
          window.localStorage.setItem("login", response.data.data);

          this.$store.commit("setAuthentication", true);
          this.$router.push("/career-list");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

can someone help me ? thank you!

Comment: What is the problem / error message that you are getting when running your code in deployment?

Comment: This question seems more adequate to be at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) 
than here. Up to now your question is too related to your own code.

Comment: hello, thank you for answering! and I get 400, the first condition

Comment: Hi @Rockcat I don't think this would be On-topic for Code Review. CR is all about reviewing code that already works as intended. Once the OP has figured out what's causing their issues and fixed it, we'd be happy to review the final result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working : I added a formData() instead of logForm object so I guess it's closed